# Swiper slider + animate css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I'm trying to connect animations (animate css) to the Swiper slider. The animations work, but there is one problem.

When you change the slide, it scrolls to the right or left, I need to remove it so that the slide disappears and appears in place through the animation.

I don’t know how much I’m doing right, I don’t understand much about JS. Look, please, can anyone know how to stop scrolling so that everything works.

codepen.io/anakin-skywalker94/pen/RmWxbE

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
    effect: 'fade',
      fadeEffect: {
    crossFade: true
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    speed: 1500,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    mousewheel: false,
    //slidePrevClass: 'swiper-slide-prev animated rotateOut',
    //slideActiveClass: 'swiper-slide-active animated bounce',
    //slideNextClass: 'swiper-slide-next animated rotateOut',   
    pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'custom',
      clickable: true,
      renderCustom: function (swiper, current, total) {
        function numberAppend(d) { return (d < 10) ? '0' + d.toString() : d.toString(); }
          return '<span>' + numberAppend(current) + '</span>' + ' <span></span> ' + '<span>' + numberAppend(total) + '</span>'; 
         }
       },
    });
```

I've basically updated your js to use fade effect and removed some of your animations.